# Referencing external xaml resources dictionary file

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a project with several classes (It's a dll project). I added a `xaml` file (let's call it `styles.xaml`) in which I declared my most commonly in-use styles.

I have another project (let's call in `prog`), in a different solution, in which I would like to use the styles written in `styles.xaml`.

I tried right clicking `prog` --> add existing item, and I selected the `styles.xaml`, wrote all the relevant code, and it worked.

The problem is that it copied the `styles.xaml` file to my `prog` project's directory (hence I'm now holding two copies of the same resource file). Unlike regular `dlls` refrencing, it will always look for it in that directory, and not copy it again if it doesn't exist.

In terms of source control, I don't want to save many copies of the same resource file, one for each application, and in the current solution it appears like I must.

I also tried to add resource, and select that file - same issue.

Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: Yes there is ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You might also go for a nuget package to hold your styles.

Comment: I did that, but that works only if I have the xaml file next to all the classes files...

Comment: added example... pack uris are not easy to grasp... had major troubles with that too

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx covers it pretty good though

Answer (score 1):

for example you have in the styles.dll:

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <SolidColorBrush  x:Key="BlueColor" Color="Blue"/>
    <!-- Whatever Styles you need -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

in a BlueTheme.xaml

then reference it with:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/styles;component/BlueTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work...Is it mandatory that both the dll and the application be under the same visual studio's solution? I'm trying to use the `xaml` file which is located under a `dll` inside one solution, inside a project which is a part of a different solution. Is that possible?

Comment: @Idanis That's why nuget packages come in handy... you have to somehow load the assembly containing the styles resource dictionary (i.e. if you got a reference to the project in the solution OR if you got a nuget-package referenced that has the resource dictionary) the compiler is not able to make guesses where the assembly is. Also look at the reference of how to make the proper pack uri... as i said it's not trivial

Comment: @Idanis The link to the reference is under your question